# jQuery: Some Checkboxes Not Included

Tags: jquery, checkbox, selector

I'm trying to add or remove html from a div whenever a checkbox is clicked, and I've gotten it to work for some, but not all of my checkboxes.

Some checkboxes were originally on the page when it loaded, and others were added dynamically.  The checkboxes that were there at the original page load time correctly do what they're supposed to do, but those which were added dynamically aren't being selected by .change() in a jQuery call.

I have placed an alert() just inside the code that should pick up on any change for checkboxes, and it only executes for the original checkboxes, but I also have checkAll and uncheckAll javascript functions which successfully do what they should for all checkboxes.

Here's the snippet taken from Firebug's Inspect Element on the area of html displaying the checkboxes in question:

```
<div class="orglist" style="background:#dddddd;color:#777777;">
Orgs to be included:
<br>
<input id="org_10346" class="ckbx" type="checkbox" checked="" value="10346" name="org_10346">
XYZ
<br>
<div id="additional">
<input id="org_3" class="ckbx" type="checkbox" checked="" value="3" name="org_3">
GHI
<br>
</div>
<b>Add an additional org:</b>
<br>
<select class="org_type " name="org_type">
<option selected="yes" value=""> </option>
<option value="company">company</option>
<option selected="yes" value="facility">facility</option>
<option value="supplier">supplier</option>
</select>
<br>
Supplier:
<select class="supplier_select" name="org_select">
<option value="ERR">***SELECT ONE***</option>
<option value="1">ABC</option>
<option value="2">DEF</option>
<option value="3">GHI</option>
</select>
<input id="addOrgID" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addOrg()">
<br>
<a href="javascript:checkAll()">Check All</a>
|
<a href="javascript:uncheckAll()">Uncheck All</a>
</div>
```

and here are the Javascript functions that should take care of things:

```
jQuery('input:checkbox, .ckbx').change(function(){
      //Loop through all checkboxes and append div for each one that's checked to the fieldset
      $tempName=this.name;
      alert($tempName);
      $theID = "#fac"+this.id.substr(4);
      $orgID = "#org"+this.id.substr(4);
      if(jQuery('input[name='+$tempName+']').val()){
        jQuery($theID).show();
        jQuery($orgID).show();
      }
      else{
        jQuery($theID).hide();
        jQuery($orgID).hide();
      }
      jQuery("select").each(function(){
          if('electricity'==this.value){
        jQuery(".elec"+this.name.substr(5)).show();
              jQuery(".gas"+this.name.substr(5)).hide();
          }
          if('gas'==this.value){
              jQuery(".elec"+this.name.substr(5)).hide();
              jQuery(".gas"+this.name.substr(5)).show();
          }
          if('both'==this.value){
        jQuery(".elec"+this.name.substr(5)).show();
        jQuery(".gas"+this.name.substr(5)).show();
          }
        });
    }).change();
    });

function checkAll(){
  jQuery(':checkbox').prop('checked', true).change();
};

function uncheckAll(){
  jQuery(':checkbox').prop('checked', false).change();
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To handle not only original checkboxes, but also the dynamically added once, you need to use event delegation with `.on`. Therefore instead of

```
jQuery('input:checkbox, .ckbx').change(function(){
```

you now need

```
jQuery('div.orglist').on('change', 'input:checkbox, .ckbx', function(){
```

Comment: Reference for event delegation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, jQuery is selecting all checkboxes that exist at load and binding to their 'change' event.  However, this binding doesn't get run again when new checkboxes are added!

One option is to bind the function to each new checkbox's `change` event as you dynamically create them.